# Check if Volume exists - via registry

Tags: c#, registry, volume

How can I check, if, let's say, G volume exists - via registry ?

Example:

I have user A and user B, and user A doesn't have volume G configured. I need to check registry to see that B has it, and A does not.

Answer (score 0):

Why using registry? This will do the trick : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx

With sample:

```
DriveInfo.GetDrives().StartsWith("G:")
```

Comment: I need to use the registry because I need to run a test that checks it for users on current machine by username/pasword. i.e I am running an exe, feeding it username and password, and I want to see if that user has G volume

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Mounted volumes are user-independent and are the same for all users.

Comment: Ohh, I see. So basically if I check for one user, it applies to all. Thanks ! :)

Comment: Yes it is. So my answer is still valid.